# Indentação no statement "else"

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, else, indentação

Qual a diferença na indentação do `else` "para fora" do `if`.
No caso é para retornar os números primos até o enésimo 'n' valor.

Primeiro caso:

```
for i in range(2, n):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Segundo caso:

```
for i in range(2, n//2):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            break
        else:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De fato, a indentação serve para definir a qual estrutura o `else` pertence. No primeiro caso, o `else` pertence ao laço `for` (sim, isso existe no Python), enquanto no segundo o `else` iria pertencer ao `if`.

```
for i in range(2, n):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Neste caso, o valor de `i` variará de 2 a `n-1` e o valor de `j` variará de 2 a `i-1`. Caso seja encontrado um valor de `j` que seja divisor de `i`, o laço de `j` será interrompido. O bloco do `else` será executado sempre que o laço terminar sem interrupção, ou seja, caso o valor de `j` chegue a `i-1`, que é seu limite superior, sem que um dos seus valores seja dividor de `i`. Se ocorrer o `break`, o bloco `else` não será executado. Vale citar que a condição `i != j`  aqui é desnecessária, pois `j` não atingirá o valor `i`, visto que seu limite superior é `i-1`.

Quanto ao segundo caso:

```
for i in range(2, n//2):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            break
        else:
            print(i)
```

O bloco `else` será executado a cada laço em `j` onde o valor de `j` não é um divisor de `i` o que provavelmente gerará um resultado bem distante do esperado.

Resumindo, a estrutura `else` em um laço de repetição servirá quando o seu laço é uma estrutura de busca e não foi encontrado o valor desejado. Se finalizar a iteração sobre o objeto no laço de repetição sem que o mesmo seja interrompido com `break`, o `else` será executado.

Comment: Nos livros que li, não curso nada só por hobby mesmo, não comentavam sobre ELSE junto com FOR, mas dessa forma gera o resultado esperado. Então essa estrutura pode ser usada é "pythonica"?

Comment: Sim, de certa forma, pois você estará utilizando a estrutura exatamente para o que ela proproem a fazer.

Answer (score 5):

No primeiro caso o `else` não é do `if` é do `for`. Se o `for` não for interrompido então cai no `else`. Então neste caso se o `i` valer menos que 2 o `else` será executado, o que me parece não fazer sentido. Isto é estranhíssimo e faz o recurso ser menos útil, então apesar do nome *senão*, se executa sempre que a execução for normal e todos os passos do laço forem executados sem sair forçadamente (`break`).

Aqui tem um exemplo mais simples de ver a diferença:

```
i = 1
for j in range(0, i):
    if j % 2 == 1:
        break
    print(j)
else:
    print("ok")
i = 3
for j in range(0, i):
    if j % 2 == 1:
        break
    print(j)
else:
    print("ok")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sWuRVO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/axzbsvom-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/ElseFor.py).

Answer (score 3):

## Testes para executar o comportamento do else

---

Realizei os seguintes testes, pensei que o `for` com `else` poderia ser afetado pelo `if`, por variáveis internas e pelo `break`, para testar executei os seguintes testes.

## Teste 1

---

- sem condicional
- sem break

**Código**

```
for i in range(2, 10):
    print("Dentro" , i)
else:
    print("Fora" , i)
```

**Resultado**

```
Dentro 2
Dentro 3
Dentro 4
Dentro 5
Dentro 6
Dentro 7
Dentro 8
Dentro 9
Fora 9
```

> else executado no ultimo índice

## Teste 2

---

- sem condicional
- com break

**Código**

```
for i in range(2, 10):
  print("Dentro" , i)
  break
else:
  print("Fora" , i)
```

**Resultado**

```
Dentro 2
```

> else não é executado

## Teste 3

---

- com condicional
- sem break
- variavel externa

**Código**

```
variavel_externa = 1
for i in range(2, 10):
  print("Dentro" , i)
  if(variavel_externa == 1):
    print('achou')
else:
  print("Fora" , i)
```

**Resultado**

```
Dentro 2
achou
Dentro 3
achou
Dentro 4
achou
Dentro 5
achou
Dentro 6
achou
Dentro 7
achou
Dentro 8
achou
Dentro 9
achou
Fora 9
```

> else executado no ultimo índice

## Teste 4

---

- com condicional
- com break
- variavel externa

**Código**

```
variavel_externa = 1
for i in range(2, 10):
  print("Dentro" , i)
  if(variavel_externa == 1):
    print('achou')
    break
else:
  print("Fora" , i)
```

**Resultado**

```
Dentro 2
achou
```

> else não é executado

## Teste 5

---

- com condicional
- sem break
- variavel interna

**Código**

```
for i in range(2, 10):
  print("Dentro" , i)
  if(i == 2):
    print('achou')
else:
  print("Fora" , i)
```

**Resultado**

```
Dentro 2
achou
Dentro 3
Dentro 4
Dentro 5
Dentro 6
Dentro 7
Dentro 8
Dentro 9
Fora 9
```

> else executado no ultimo índice

## Teste 6

---

- com condicional
- com break
- variavel interna

**Código**

```
for i in range(2, 10):
  print("Dentro" , i)
  if(i == 2):
    print('achou')
    break
else:
  print("Fora" , i)
```

**Resultado**

```
Dentro 2
achou
```

> else não é executado

## Teste com o código da pergunta

---

- com condicional
- com break
- variavel interna

**Código**

```
for i in range(2, 10):
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            print('break', i)
            break
    else:
        print(i)
```

**Resultado**

```
2
3
break 4
5
break 6
7
break 8
break 9
```

> else não é executado quando o break não é executado

## Conclusão

---

Ele só não executa o else quando o "break" é executado.